# classifications of all weak factorisation systems on a category

Tags: simplicial-stuff, model-categories, simplicial-categories

Is there an example of a category where all the weak factorisation systems have been classified ? Is this something that people tried to classify ?

This can be done trivially for Sets ([see the calculation all the model structures on Sets](https://www.matem.unam.mx/%7Eomar/notes/modelcatsets.html)) and the category of vector spaces (finite dimensional or not). For the category of modules over a nice enough ring this is already not entirely trivial I think. Did anyone look at this for the category of simplicial sets ?